# Some problems in Pivot and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Help I have this code, it outputs well where I can see who has the Warehouse or Trip in the item in that selected date but I want to ouput also when the Beg Bal is not 0 even if there's nothing happened in the warehouse and trip table in that selected date.

Here is the Code

```
Declare @to DATETIME
Set @to = '2016-11-15'

;WITH tTable AS(

Select i.ItemCode,Goods.Description,wQty,tQty,TripName,
(Select ISNULL(SUM(fgd.Quantity),0)
From FinishedGoodsDetails fgd 
LEFT JOIN FinishedGoods fg
ON fg.DeliveryReceiptNumber = fgd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
LEFT JOIN Warehouse w
ON w.WarehouseID = fg.WarehouseID
WHERE fg.CreatedOn < @to
AND fgd.ItemID = i.ItemID
AND fg.Status IN ('X','C')) - 
(Select ISNULL(SUM(drd.Quantity),0)
From DeliveryReceiptDetails drd
LEFT JOIN DeliveryReceipt dr
ON dr.DeliveryReceiptNumber = drd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
LEFT JOIN Trip t
ON t.TripID = dr.TripID
WHERE dr.DeliveredOn < @to
AND drd.ItemID = i.ItemID
AND dr.Status IN ('X','C')) AS 'Beg Bal',
(Select ISNULL(SUM(fgd.Quantity),0)
From FinishedGoodsDetails fgd 
LEFT JOIN FinishedGoods fg
ON fg.DeliveryReceiptNumber = fgd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
LEFT JOIN Warehouse w
ON w.WarehouseID = fg.WarehouseID
WHERE fg.CreatedOn < @to
AND fgd.ItemID = i.ItemID
AND fg.Status IN ('X','C')) - 
(Select ISNULL(SUM(drd.Quantity),0)
From DeliveryReceiptDetails drd
LEFT JOIN DeliveryReceipt dr
ON dr.DeliveryReceiptNumber = drd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
LEFT JOIN Trip t
ON t.TripID = dr.TripID
WHERE dr.DeliveredOn < @to
AND drd.ItemID = i.ItemID
AND dr.Status IN ('X','C')) + 
((Select ISNULL(SUM(fgd.Quantity),0)
From FinishedGoodsDetails fgd 
LEFT JOIN FinishedGoods fg
ON fg.DeliveryReceiptNumber = fgd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
LEFT JOIN Warehouse w
ON w.WarehouseID = fg.WarehouseID
WHERE fg.CreatedOn = @to
AND fgd.ItemID = i.ItemID
AND fg.Status IN ('X','C')) - 
(Select ISNULL(SUM(drd.Quantity),0) From DeliveryReceiptDetails drd
LEFT JOIN DeliveryReceipt dr
ON dr.DeliveryReceiptNumber = drd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
LEFT JOIN Trip t
ON t.TripID = dr.TripID
WHERE dr.DeliveredOn = @to
AND drd.ItemID = i.ItemID
AND dr.Status IN ('X','C')))
AS 'End Bal'

From Item i

LEFT JOIN
(Select ItemID,w.Description,ISNULL(SUM(fgd.Quantity),0) AS wQty From FinishedGoodsDetails fgd 
LEFT JOIN FinishedGoods fg
ON fg.DeliveryReceiptNumber = fgd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
LEFT JOIN Warehouse w
ON w.WarehouseID = fg.WarehouseID
WHERE fg.CreatedOn = @to
AND fg.Status IN ('X','C')
GROUP BY w.Description,fgd.ItemID) Goods
ON Goods.ItemID = i.ItemID

INNER JOIN
(Select ItemID,t.TripName,ISNULL(SUM(drd.Quantity),0) AS tQty From DeliveryReceiptDetails drd
LEFT JOIN DeliveryReceipt dr
ON dr.DeliveryReceiptNumber = drd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
LEFT JOIN Trip t
ON t.TripID = dr.TripID
WHERE dr.DeliveredOn = @to
AND dr.Status IN ('X','C')

GROUP BY t.TripName,drd.ItemID) Delivery
ON Delivery.ItemID = i.ItemID
)

Select * From tTable

Pivot
(SUM(wQty) FOR Description IN ([PRODN],[ADJ PCS],[BALASING],[RETURN PAM],
[RETURN BAT],[RETURN STM],[RETURN MAL],[RETURN SP],
[RET.SMKT1],[RET.SMKT2],[RET.SMKT3],[RET.SMKT4])) pivot1

Pivot
(SUM(tQty) FOR TripName IN ([C1],[C2],[C3],[C4],
[C5],[FAIR],[NOVA],[STM],
[MAL],[SP],[PAM],[SMKT1],
[SMKT2],[SMKT3],[SMKT4])) pivot2
```

What if there is an item code C800 with BegBal 50 but there's nothing happened in the warehouse or trip in that selected date? 
The output is:

```
ItemCode Beg Bal End Bal PRODN ...... SMK4 
C900     270     272     64    ...... 50
```

Expected Output is:

```
ItemCode Beg Bal End Bal PRODN ...... SMK4 
C800     50      50      0     ...... 0 
C900     270     272     64    ...... 50
```

Comment: Please edit your question: 1. add indentation to your code. 2. don't post additional data in comments post it in the question

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need a LEFT JOIN to the subquery "Delivery" *(instead of INNER JOIN)*

```
DECLARE @to datetime
SET @to = '2016-11-15'

;WITH
      tTable AS (

                  SELECT
                        i.ItemCode
                      , Goods.Description
                      , wQty
                      , tQty
                      , TripName
                      , (
                              SELECT
                                    ISNULL(SUM(fgd.Quantity), 0)
                              FROM FinishedGoodsDetails fgd
                              LEFT JOIN FinishedGoods fg ON fg.DeliveryReceiptNumber = fgd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
                              LEFT JOIN Warehouse w ON w.WarehouseID = fg.WarehouseID
                              WHERE fg.CreatedOn < @to
                              AND fgd.ItemID = i.ItemID
                              AND fg.Status IN ('X', 'C')
                        )
                        - (
                              SELECT
                                    ISNULL(SUM(drd.Quantity), 0)
                              FROM DeliveryReceiptDetails drd
                              LEFT JOIN DeliveryReceipt dr ON dr.DeliveryReceiptNumber = drd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
                              LEFT JOIN Trip t ON t.TripID = dr.TripID
                              WHERE dr.DeliveredOn < @to
                              AND drd.ItemID = i.ItemID
                              AND dr.Status IN ('X', 'C')
                        )
                        AS 'Beg Bal'
                      , (
                              SELECT
                                    ISNULL(SUM(fgd.Quantity), 0)
                              FROM FinishedGoodsDetails fgd
                              LEFT JOIN FinishedGoods fg ON fg.DeliveryReceiptNumber = fgd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
                              LEFT JOIN Warehouse w ON w.WarehouseID = fg.WarehouseID
                              WHERE fg.CreatedOn < @to
                              AND fgd.ItemID = i.ItemID
                              AND fg.Status IN ('X', 'C')
                        )
                        - (
                              SELECT
                                    ISNULL(SUM(drd.Quantity), 0)
                              FROM DeliveryReceiptDetails drd
                              LEFT JOIN DeliveryReceipt dr ON dr.DeliveryReceiptNumber = drd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
                              LEFT JOIN Trip t ON t.TripID = dr.TripID
                              WHERE dr.DeliveredOn < @to
                              AND drd.ItemID = i.ItemID
                              AND dr.Status IN ('X', 'C')
                        )
                        +
                        ((
                              SELECT
                                    ISNULL(SUM(fgd.Quantity), 0)
                              FROM FinishedGoodsDetails fgd
                              LEFT JOIN FinishedGoods fg ON fg.DeliveryReceiptNumber = fgd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
                              LEFT JOIN Warehouse w ON w.WarehouseID = fg.WarehouseID
                              WHERE fg.CreatedOn = @to
                              AND fgd.ItemID = i.ItemID
                              AND fg.Status IN ('X', 'C')
                        )
                        - (
                              SELECT
                                    ISNULL(SUM(drd.Quantity), 0)
                              FROM DeliveryReceiptDetails drd
                              LEFT JOIN DeliveryReceipt dr ON dr.DeliveryReceiptNumber = drd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
                              LEFT JOIN Trip t ON t.TripID = dr.TripID
                              WHERE dr.DeliveredOn = @to
                              AND drd.ItemID = i.ItemID
                              AND dr.Status IN ('X', 'C')
                        )
                        )
                        AS 'End Bal'

                  FROM Item i

                  LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT
                              ItemID
                            , w.Description
                            , ISNULL(SUM(fgd.Quantity), 0) AS wQty
                        FROM FinishedGoodsDetails fgd
                        LEFT JOIN FinishedGoods fg ON fg.DeliveryReceiptNumber = fgd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
                        LEFT JOIN Warehouse w ON w.WarehouseID = fg.WarehouseID
                        WHERE fg.CreatedOn = @to
                        AND fg.Status IN ('X', 'C')
                        GROUP BY
                              w.Description
                            , fgd.ItemID
                  ) Goods ON Goods.ItemID = i.ItemID
/* CHANGED JOIN BELOW */
                  LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT
                              ItemID
                            , t.TripName
                            , ISNULL(SUM(drd.Quantity), 0) AS tQty
                        FROM DeliveryReceiptDetails drd
                        LEFT JOIN DeliveryReceipt dr ON dr.DeliveryReceiptNumber = drd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
                        LEFT JOIN Trip t ON t.TripID = dr.TripID
                        WHERE dr.DeliveredOn = @to
                        AND dr.Status IN ('X', 'C')

                        GROUP BY
                              t.TripName
                            , drd.ItemID
                  ) Delivery ON Delivery.ItemID = i.ItemID
            )
SELECT
      *
FROM tTable
```

I wasn't sure why you presented 2 pivot snippets neither are included in the query above.

I have to say that you are using several "correlated subqueries" in the select clause of tTable such as this:

```
, (
      SELECT
            ISNULL(SUM(fgd.Quantity), 0)
      FROM FinishedGoodsDetails fgd
      LEFT JOIN FinishedGoods fg ON fg.DeliveryReceiptNumber = fgd.DeliveryReceiptNumber
      LEFT JOIN Warehouse w ON w.WarehouseID = fg.WarehouseID
      WHERE fg.CreatedOn < @to
      AND fgd.ItemID = i.ItemID
      AND fg.Status IN ('X', 'C')
  )
```

Often this type of correlated subquery is a performance issue, and in SQL Server you might get benefits by moving that style of logic into either a CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY.